# What cognitively interesting event-related potentials at FP1, FP2, TP9 or TP10 can be measured with consumer-grade EEG hardware?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, cognitive-neuroscience, eeg, event-related-potential

I'm looking for cognitively interesting event-related potentials at places like FP1, FP2, TP9 or TP10 that can be measured with consumer-grade EEG hardware. Right now I have an Interaxon Muse EEG and want to see how effective it can be for capturing ERPs.  Does anyone have any experience/recommendations?

Comment: FP1, FP2, TP9 and TP10 are some of the worst places to look at if you want to see cognitive activity, incidentally.

Comment: This is kind of the inverse order of doing research. Normally you form a hypothesis based on literature after which you look for the appropriate tool.  It seems you take a tool-oriented design, as opposed to a goal-oriented design. How come?

Comment: With this question, I'm looking to see what is possible with consumer-grade products where research can be crowdsourced (relatively) cheaply. This boosts the potential sample size for various studies, and also makes it more practical to do personalized discovery research -- how does *my* brain respond in these situations, how does that change in various conditions, how is it different than others, etc. I realize that there are statistical caveats and tradeoffs involved, especially given the noise level of EEG. But I think that progress can be made while being mindful of these factors.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have experience with consumer grade EEG,  but at fp1 and fp2 you should be able to measure the P3a response. Given the high impedance you will need a lot of trials,  but the response is typically seen at fp1 and fp2 in research. 
http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0168559798000331

For the Tp sites they are a bit posterior but you may be able to pick up the T complex.  Typically this response is measured at more anterior sites. 
http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1388245703000051